# Arranging a list by given order in python for dump into json

Tags: python, json, sorting

I have list of lists with items in wrong positions. And I want to reorder them in defined way and write into file for future usage.

**python 2.7.3**

What I have:

```
data_in = [..., [a1, a4, a0, a2, a3], ...] # where a0..a4 - some values
order_key = [2,0,3,4,1] # "2" means: in place with index 0 shall be item with index 2
```

In result it shall be:

```
file.jsons:
prefix [ ... ] \n
prefix [a0, a1, a2, a3, a4] \n
prefix [ ... ] \n
```

I do it in such "naive" way:

```
import json
from itertools import imap
formatter = "prefix {} \n".format
with open('file.jsons') as f:
    f.writelines( imap(formatter, imap(json.dumps,([row[i] for i in order_key] for row in data_in ))))
    # ([row[i] for i in order_key] for row in data_in ) - generator: yields arranged rows
    # imap(json.dumps, ...) - generator: dumps lists into json strings
    # imap(formatter, ... ) - generator: formats strings in proper way
    # f.writelines( .. ) - consumes and writes to file
```

I have some questions:

- Is it a proper way to rearrange? to dump?
- Is there any faster methods? (I need to do this as fast as possible)
- Shall I use json.dumps()/json.reads() or str()/eval() - I know that it is a very
  very bad practice, but I am sure in myself as a safe data provider.

Comment: Why the downvote on this question?  Seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: I think, It is because of my poor English. Question looks like "review my code!", but I can't write better. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helo,

I don't particularly know json. But your code seems to me carefully crafted.
If the order in **order_key = [2,0,3,4,1]** is stable, it think it may be faster to use a supplementary function:

```
import json
from itertools import imap
# order_key = [2,0,3,4,1] 

formatter = "prefix {} \n".format

def reorder(x):
    return (x[2],x[0],x[3],x[4],x[1])

with open('file.jsons') as f:
    f.writelines( imap(formatter,
                       imap(json.dumps,
                            (reorder[row) for row in data_in ))))
```

I don't see anything criticable in your question, so I upvote against the downvote

## EDIT

```
order_key = [2,0,3,4,1]

exec('def reorder(x):\n    return (%s)'
     % ' , '.join( 'x[%d]' % i for i in (order_key)))

cn = (111,444 ,000,222,333)
cv = ['a1', 'a4', 'a0', 'a2', 'a3']
cx = ('one','four','zero','two','three')

print map(reorder,(cn,cv,cx))
```

result

```
[(0, 111, 222, 333, 444), ('a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'),('zero', 'one', 'second', 'third', 'four')]
```

Comment: order_key is known, but not stable from one run to other but defines once per run. How do you think, is it good to define reorder function on-the-fly? I mean smth like `reorder = eval("def reorder(x):\n\t return("+",".join(..)+..+")")` or this replacement doesn't add any performance?

Comment: @akaRem Defining ``reorder`` on the fly, that's what I tried to do, with the expression ``' , '.join( 'x[%s]' % i for i in (order_key))`` but I don't succeed. Yes I think it should be better relatively to performance.

Comment: thanks! There is last question about json and eval, but I'll try to find answer in other topics.

Comment: @akaRem I found how to declare a function on the fly: with ``exec``, not ``eval``. See my edit p^lease

Answer (score 1):

What you have here isn't actually unreasonable in any way that I can see.  A couple of intermediary steps to improve readability would help from a stylistic perspective (why the focus on a single line solution?).  You might also look at the `pickle` and `shelve` modules if the file is only used by your program.

Comment: json strings are readable and editable. pickle and shelve are good, db are even better, but i can't read them in notepad or SublimeText (I mean by eyes).

Comment: what about json vs eval? If not to think about perfomance, the main problem here is back-compatibility: python evals single and double quoted values (`{'a':1}`-ok, `{"a":1}`-ok) but json reads only double-quoted (`{"a":1}`) So I can do things in "right way" (json) and later start to do them "wrong" with eval, but not vice versa. And this is a reason to think twice.